# What command lines should I use for the following?

Tags: command-line, grep, sort, processes

What command lines should I use for...

1. printing a list of users running bash now in alphabetical order
2. print the count of users who are running bash right now
3. save the list of users who are running bash right now AND print the count

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're not very familiar with Unix yet, or you wouldn't ask this, so I'm going to include the thought process by which you'd arrive at a command like this. You'll be able to find the next one on your own then.

First, you need to get a list of running processes. To list the running processes, you use `ps`. You probably already know that, but it's a good place to start. You've seen commands like `ps ax`, which would mean list all (`a`), even those without an associated tty (`x`).

So now need to tell it to select all processes (`a`), and to display the filename of the executables (`c`). You could include an `x` or not: any interactive `bash` will certainly have an associated tty, but a shell script may not, so whether to include it depends on what you need. In order to make it easier to parse its output, it's also handy to restrict its output to the values we're interested in, namely the user and the command (`o user,command`).

That gives the following:

```
$ ps aco user,command
root   login
root   bash
user   bash
root   bash
user   lynx
...
```

Now you need to filter it to find the `bash` instances for each user. For that, you can pipe it to `awk`, using the script `$2=="bash" { print $1 }`, which means, "if the 2nd column is "bash", print the first column".

```
$ ps aco user,command | awk '$2=="bash" {print $1}'
root
user
root
```

Finally, you want to sort the output and remove duplicates, using `sort` and `uniq`.

```
$ ps aco user,command | awk '$2=="bash" {print $1}' | sort | uniq
root
user
```

If you want the *amount* of users running 'bash', you can just count the lines in the output of that:

```
$ ps aco user,command | awk '$2=="bash" {print $1}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
2
```

Then, you can write the output of those to a file by using output redirection, i.e. `command > file`.